# Run OpenCV project exe on different computers

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv, exe

I have built an `OpenCV` project with `Visual Studio 2008`. When I run the exe from the project folder, it runs perfectly on my machine (windows 7). I would like to run this exe on any windows 7 machine. I have included all the dlls in the folder with the exe. My `OpenCV` project loads an image, so I have included that image. In the project I have loaded the image from the C drive("C://mypic.jpg") so when I am running the exe on a different machine I will need to move the image to that C drive.

I have done all this and when I try run it on a different machine that does not have visual studio or any programming enivironment, I get this error.
"The application has failed  to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the        application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more details"

Can anyone helpme with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building an OpenCV application with Visual Studio 2008 and running it from another computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539980/building-an-opencv-application-with-visual-studio-2008-and-running-it-from-anoth)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you'll probably need to install the [Visual Studio 2008 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582&WT.mc_id=MSCOM_EN_US_DLC_DETAILS_121LSUS007998) package. The correct way to deploy an application on Windows is to create an installer. If you have Visual Studio 2008 Professional, you should be able to create an installer for your project. [Here](http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/blog/2009/12/17/creating-your-msi-installer-using-visual-studio-2008) is a good guide to get you started. If you need a free alternative for creating installers, check out the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) opensource installer generator.